# using Pi Zero W GPIO relay control

Tags: gpio, relay, wiringpi

I am trying to control my relay with Raspberry GPIO.
Using the terminal to write to gpio5 (Physical 18, BCM 24) works:

```
gpio mode 5 out
gpio write 5 1
```

Trying to do the same in my c++ code doesn't work:

```
wiringPiSetup();
pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
```

wiringPiSetup() should give me the right pinout. What am I missing?

Comment: "What am I missing" - code

Comment: I don't understand your problem.  Is it true that your problem has nothing to do with the relay, it is only that your C++ program cannot set the GPIO pin High.  In other words, it is a WiringPi C++ GPIO problem?

Comment: Since it works by "manually" via command line setting pin 5 to high, I dont't think it is a problem with the relay. Checking gpio readall does not even show my pin set as output after running the code.

Comment: OK.  So the problem is not even if you can set the GPIO High.  It is you cannot even set the GPIO pin to output mode.  In other words, we can forget everything else and now look at only the first two statements of your C++ code.  Well, perhaps your GPIO pin is broken.  Why not try another pin?

Comment: do not assume that the output pin does not change when the program ends ... put a 1 second delay at the end

Comment: @jsotola, Ah, you remind us one important thing - When the program ends, All GPIO pins go back to input mode.  So delay a while, or ask the user to hit any key to end the program.  I guess this the bug of the OP's ridiculous short, two line program! :)

Comment: Program isn't that short, i wanted to show what commands I am using. I just found the problem. I was compiling my code with PlatformIO remote. Looks like there is a problem with wiringPi framework by doing that. It is working now...

Comment: @K.S. Ah, when I said your program is 2 statements short, I meant we narrowed down to two lines when debugging. I agree it is difficult to decide how much info to provide to the forum for troubleshooting advice.  StackOverflow has a recommendation of "Mininmal, Comprehensive, Verifiable, Example (MCVE) ，　．．http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-deprecated/